# how to generate the JSon file from a csv file?

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to create a json schema file from a csv file using python.
( i am trying to create a Json schema file for my pyspark code from oracle table metadata)

```
fields,CURR_NBR,VARCHAR2,true
fields,CURR_AMT,NUMBER,true
fields,MILEAGE_CD,VARCHAR2,true
```

How can i generate a json structure as like below

```
{
  "type": "struct",
  "fields": [
    {
      "metadata": {},
      "name": "CURR_NBR",
      "nullable": true,
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "metadata": {},
      "name": "CURR_AMT",
      "nullable": true,
      "type": "integer"
    },
    {
      "metadata": {},
      "name": "MILEAGE_CD",
      "nullable": true,
      "type": "string"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: The structured table you provide and the JSON structure do not contain much in comon. For example, What is "acct_dim_id" because that's not clearly visible in the CSV

Comment: why do you need to create a schema ? what are you trying to read in pyspark that requires a schema beforehand ? I think you are trying to make things that are more complex than they should. Please explain the real goal behind. You probably do not need this step. *Sounds like a [XY_problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)*

Comment: I am trying copy data from oracle to s3 for apply pyspark jobs. so for the pyspark job i would need a schema to read which i would like to generate from oracle metadata tables

Comment: When reading data from oracle with pyspark, spark gets directly the table schema.

Comment: we are extracting data from oracle to flat file and sending to s3 and then applying spark jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can access your DB with Spark, it is better to extract the data directly with pyspark from the DB.

```py
spark.read.jdbc(...)
```

---

Let's assume for any (bad) reason, you do not want to read the DB but only flat files which have the same schema than the table, then you can still get the schema from the DB:

```py
schm = spark.read.jdbc(...).load().schema
df = spark.read.csv("/path/to/csv", schema=schm)
```